# FieldValue.increment produce the wrong sum when using decimals

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field '`winning`' in firestore database whose value is **988.95** .
[image]

I want to decrease value by **500** or whatever user inputs in ediitext.
Suppose here user entered 500.
But by doing
`FieldValue.increment(-1*(Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText().toString().trim())))` ;

writes value **488.95000000005** in database [image]

Why is it even happening? Why cant just 488.95 be written in firestore?

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-the-database-schemas-for-our-firebase-shopping-app-part-2-29f8bcac7acb) will help, as it explains why it is not recommended to use floating point numbers.

Comment: @AlexMamo it's paywalled

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is quite common in any system that uses floating point to store fractional numerical values.

The normal way to prevent this is to not store monetary amounts in floating point values, but either storing them in a fixed point value or in whole numerical values of the smallest denomination of the currency.

In Firestore the latter option would be the only way to go, meaning you'd store the value of `winnning` as cents. So

```
winning: 48895
```

As long as you make sure to only perform operations with other whole numbers, the value will remain an integer/long and the only time you'll have to devide it by 100 is to display the value to the user.

Also see:

- [How to store currency values in Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809591/how-to-store-currency-values-in-realtime-database)
- [How to convert string to number and store it in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124711/how-to-convert-string-to-number-and-store-it-in-firestore)
- [How to Store / Use Decimal and money values in firestore / nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507643/how-to-store-use-decimal-and-money-values-in-firestore-nodejs)
- [Cloud Firestore saves the number with unnecessary decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138860/cloud-firestore-saves-the-number-with-unnecessary-decimal-places)